# Turn off loggin

Tags: itext7

Trying to turn off loggin but missing something as i'm still getting log output.

log4j.properities:

```
 org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor=OFF
```

-Dlog4j.debug

```
log4j: Using URL [file:...../resources/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
    log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:....../resources/log4j.properties
    log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[OFF].
    log4j: Level token is [OFF].
    log4j: Category root set to OFF
    log4j: Parsing for [com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor] with value=[OFF].
    log4j: Level token is [OFF].
    log4j: Category com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor set to OFF
    log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor=[null]
    log4j: Finished configuring.
    [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag properties
```

Answer (score 0):

we log off for same package by adding below into applicaion.yml file in spring boot project.

```
logging:
  level:
    com.netflix.*: OFF
```